# How to slide auto in page

Tags: jquery, slide

```
<div id="nav">
    <li><a href="#menu1">menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu2">menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu3">menu3</a></li>
</div>

<div id="contents">
    <h1 id=menu1></h1>
    <h1 id=menu2></h1>
    <h1 id=menu3></h3>
</div>
```

I made one page included three contents and link to their id.
Using jquery, How to scroll auto smoothly when click menu in nav?

Comment: I'm sure you have tried something, no?

Comment: For this kind of complex task which has not been answered thousand times, you should consider to hire a complete team of developper. Or maybe try something yourself...

Comment: @roasted Yes, You're right, I am shamed. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/

## HTML

```
<ul id="top-menu">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Top</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#baz">Baz</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<a id="foo">Foo</a>
<a id="bar">Bar</a>
<a id="baz">Baz</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this

```
$('.menu').click(function(){     

     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#cmenu1").offset().top}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you could do this, more classical way:

http://jsfiddle.net/UUxq6/

```
$('#nav a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(this.href.split('/').pop()).offset().top
     }, 2000);
});
```